# Mongodb: Aggregation : sum up values in an array before $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents with the following structure:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    array: [
        {value: 10 },
        {value: 11 },
        {value: 12 }
    ]
}
```

**I want make an aggregate query on the collection:**
get the proportion of each item. (i.e. for example the proportion of item 1 would be `value` of item 1 divided by the sum of the values of all three items.

***Note:*** I want to do this within a single query.

Comment: What have you tried? Also submit a valid document with your question as this is not valid JSON ( therefore BSON ) notation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic idea here is to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array, [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) the document and then apply to each array member. This works better for MongoDB 2.6 or greater due to the [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "array": { "$push": "$array" },
       "total": { "$sum": "$array.value" }
    }},
    { "$project": {
        "array": {
            "$map": {
                "input": "$array",
                "as": "el",
                "in": {
                    "value": "$$el.value",
                    "prop": { 
                        "$divide": [ "$$el.value", "$total" ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

Or with earlier versions:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$group": {
       "_id": "$_id",
       "array": { "$push": "$array" },
       "total": { "$sum": "$array.value" }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$array" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "array": {
            "$push": {
                "value": "$array.value",
                "prop": {
                    "$divide": [ "$array.value", "$total" ]
                }
            }
        }
    }}
])
```

In either case, if you are not actually "aggregating" anything beyond the document, it is far more efficient to do this calculation in client code. The `$unwind` here can get very costly due to what it does.

Also if you just stored the "total" as another element, then the simple **`$project`** is all that you need, which comes at very little cost by itself. Keeping a total on updates is just simple usage of the [**`$inc`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator as you [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) new elements to the array.

Comment: Cool idea with `$map`. I did not know about it.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Here is the aggregation pipeline you need:

```
[
    {$unwind: '$array'},
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id', 
            array: {$push: '$array'}, 
            sum: {$sum: '$array.value'}
        }
    }, 
    {$unwind: '$array'},
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 1,
           'array.value': 1, 
           'array.proportion': {
               $divide: ['$array.value', '$sum']
           }
        }
    }
]
```